# Variable change as model time passes-

Tags: anylogic

My model time is in minutes. I have a variable that changes as the model time passes. For example if its 17.34 minutes simulation has passed the variable should be 17. It should read the time of simulation passed but in integers.

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. Please refer to [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), in order to help other people understand what you already tried. A good place to start would be by adding some code sample that you tried but does not provide the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is....

```
(int)floor(time(MINUTE))
```

you can run an event if you want cyclically every minute and on the action do:

```
variable=(int)floor(time(MINUTE));
```